# If “latter” comes first, and “former” comes second, what comes third? Or fourth?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, word-order, syntactic-analysis, errors

If we had an hour long discussion, and discussed 5 topics: A, B, C, D and E in order, to the extent that we are talking about "E" right now, if "D" is the latter, and "C" is the former, what is "B" to be called, following this "latter, former" syntax? Does such a word exist?

Bonus question:
- What about A?

EDIT (for the regulars, the editors, the potential downvoters): If you think that "former" and "latter" are "only allowed to be used when referencing 2 objects", you're right, yes, "former" and "latter" *are* only to be used for referencing 2 objects. *However*, there is always a third object which comes before the former object. You say the former object came first per the definition of "latter" but that's obviously not true in all cases (conversations, interactions, etc). In some cases, the former object might want to reference it's antecedent if it indeed has one. If you've only had two prior interactions with a person, the former would indeed be the first. But if you've had three prior interactions, then there would be an object before the former, wouldn't there?

If now is t(0), then the latter is t(-1), the former is t(-2), and the word I'm looking for is t(-3). The bonus, of course, is t(-4).

Comment: Latter and former don't mean what you seem to think they do.

Comment: What I *want* them to do, Mark. What I *need* them to do. I've run into this problem when discussing things with friends and professionals, sometimes you just need a third word after the "latter, former" series. People are getting smarter, Mark, we need these things.

Comment: Cambridge (ref'd prev 2 edit) is the source of The English Language as we know it from the Oxford/Cambridge press. It's an offshoot of one of the oldest still-existing universities in the world (c. 1300 at least), Oxford, and was created to get away from the "riff-raff" which was presumably Oxford. It's the elitests' elitist university. They all used to know Latin &/or Greek and they basically invented words as they needed them, because they (Oxbridge) were the master editors of The Dictionary. Harvard & MIT have nodded to Cambridge University by renaming their suburb of Boston to "Cambridge".

Comment: Strange that you encounter *lattermost*, but never *formermost*.

Comment: @tchrist "foremost" is what you find for "formermost".

Comment: You've misunderstood how the two words work. There is no lexical gap here. 'Former' and'latter' work for a sequence of exactly two items. For more than two items, you can use ordinals and 'first' and 'last'. If you're using 'former' and 'latter' when talking to people about a sequence of more than two, then people will wonder why you insist on misusing them that way.

Comment: If now is t(0), then t(-1) is the _previous_, or the _most recent_, not the _latter_.  [_Latter_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=latter&ls=a) specifically means _the second of two_, not _the second in a list_.

Comment: _Latter_ doesn't come first, it comes second. And (perhaps unsurprisingly, by now), _former_ doesn't come second, it comes first.  

E.g. "Today I got a house, and then a car. The former was a purchase, but the latter was a gift." The gift is the _car_.

Answer (score 7):

As you indicated, "former" and "latter" are understood as referring to 2 items. When you have more than 2 items, it will be less confusing to avoid using "former" and "latter".

If you have 3 or more items, the last one is simply the "last".* Before that are the "next to last" or "penultimate", etc. The first one would be the "first".

*Interesting note: Historically, "[last](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=last&allowed_in_frame=0)" was the superlative of "[latter](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=latter&allowed_in_frame=0)" which in turn was the comparative of "late". This is similarly true for "former" and "[foremost](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=foremost&allowed_in_frame=0)". Of course today they have taken on frozen meanings are aren't really seen as comparative degrees any more.

Comment: In case others don't know (as I didn't; I looked them up when I saw the *etc.* above), the one before the *penultimate* is the *antepenultimate*, and the one before that the *preantepenultimate*. These are somewhat rare terms, though, coming from the study of phonetics, but I figured it's worth noting that they exist if you really need a single word.